# Proper way to make a call to an Endpoint from the API using Flask

Tags: python, api, flask

I'm trying to build a Flask API and I have one endpoint that is supposed to create a user and another one that is suppose to check if a user is present  in the database:

```
@API.route('/users/', methods=['POST'])
def new_user():
    user_json = json.loads(request.get_json())
    first_name = user_json.get('first_name')
    last_name = user_json.get('last_name')
    email = user_json.get('email')
    password = user_json.get('password')
    # Call the other endpoint here
    if response == 400:
        try:
           user = User(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, password=password)
           db.session.add(user)
           db.session.commit()
           return jsonify(user=user.to_json()), 200
       except:
           return jsonify(error=500), 500
    else:
       return jsonify(user=user.to_json()), 409



@API.route('/users/<string:email>', methods=['GET'])
def is_present(email):
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    if user:
        print(user)
        return jsonify(user=user.to_json()), 200
    else:
        return jsonify(error=404), 404
```

The problem is I don't know what is the best way to call my `is_present` in the `new_user` endpoint. Should I use `requests.get` ? Or is there a specific other to do so in Flask?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common way to handle this is to factor out the view's logic into a separate internal function (i.e. not exposed via the API), and to call the internal function instead. The views will then deal with the request, making a call to the internal function as required. Although it is trivial in this case (it's just a database lookup), this is how it could be done:

```
def get_user(email):
    return User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

@API.route('/users/', methods=['POST'])
def new_user():
    user_json = json.loads(request.get_json())
    first_name = user_json.get('first_name')
    last_name = user_json.get('last_name')
    email = user_json.get('email')
    password = user_json.get('password')
    user = get_user(email)
    if not user:
        try:
           user = User(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, password=password)
           db.session.add(user)
           db.session.commit()
           return jsonify(user=user.to_json()), 200
       except:
           return jsonify(error=500), 500
    else:
       return jsonify(user=user.to_json()), 409

@API.route('/users/<string:email>', methods=['GET'])
def is_present(email):
    user = get_user(email)
    if user:
        print(user)
        return jsonify(user=user.to_json()), 200
    else:
        return jsonify(error=404), 404
```

One obvious advantage of using this method is that the HTTP request is completely avoided, resulting in a more efficient and less error prone (network issues for example) solution.

---

Having said the above as a way of generally dealing with accessing common functionality from multiple views, performing the lookup before creating the new user can not always guarantee that user creation will not fail due to duplicate records. There's a race condition; it is possible for another request to create the user after the first request checks but before it attempts the create operation.

Assuming that your user table has a primary key, e.g. on `(first_name, last_name, email)`, you can simply attempt to create a new user and handle any exception that is raised due to duplicates. Or you might like to look at [`Session.merge()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.merge)

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip! I want to code properly, where should I put function like 'get_user' in my repository? if I still have a endpoint that need to access another one how should I do that?

Comment: If you insist on making the HTTP request, `requests` is a great option. Flask does provide [`test_client()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.test_client) so you could use that if you can get over it being named a "test" client and not a generic HTTP client.

Comment: Where to put `get_user()`? If you have a models file it could go there, otherwise wherever the `User` class is declared would seem the best place.

Answer (score 4):

I would do something like this for your use-case:

```
@API.route('/users', defaults={'email': None} ,methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@API.route('/users/<string:email>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_user(email):
    if(email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if user:
            return jsonify(user=user.to_json()), 200
        else:
            return jsonify(error=404), 404
    else:
        user_json = json.loads(request.get_json())
        first_name = user_json.get('first_name')
        last_name = user_json.get('last_name')
        email = user_json.get('email')
        password = user_json.get('password')
        user = User(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, password=password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify(user=user.to_json()), 200
```

Comment: I have a similar question about calling an HTTPs API Endpoint using Python Flask Framework. 
Route is not always simple like /users
or 
When I have an API Endpoint like https://dummy-domain.com/testapi/user1
Then How do I pass on the whole URL including domain and https?

Comment: Sorry Varun. It's been many years that I have not touched the Flask framework. Maybe ask a new question. someone might know the answer.